# Binding window.open response object to an html element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here I'm trying to use `.data()` to store the object data from the `window.open` function.
But it doesn't seem to work, all I get is `undefined` for the `dataWin` variable.

I'm wondering how to accomplish a function that will open a new window when a window isn't open, otherwise only `.focus()` on an already open window, using `window.open`. Because when I use `window.open` on the same window name it causes the new window to refresh, which is a problem for my app.

If there is a way to store an object into variable so it can be binded to a unique html element?
I try and just get `undefined`

Or, Is there a way to check if a window is already open by WINDOW NAME?
(After searching on google didn't find anything that could do it)

Anyways here's what I'm trying, without any luck:

```
function OpenNewWindow_Or_FocusOpenWindow(name) {

dataWin = $("#id-" + name).data('winData')

if (dataWin == 'undefined') { windowClosed = true }
else { windowClosed = dataWin.closed }


  if ( windowClosed == true ) {
    newWin = window.open('myurl' , "win" + name , 'options');
    $("#id-" + name).data('winData',newWin);
    if (newWin != null) { newWin.focus() }
  }
  else {
    dataWin.focus();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `dataWin`, `newWin` and `windowClosed` as global variables. Scope them to the local function. Apart from that your check for undefined is wrong. Here is a revised version of your code, which will do what you want:

```
function OpenNewWindow_Or_FocusOpenWindow(name) {
  var el = $("#id-" + name),
      dataWin = el.data('winData'),
      windowClosed,
      newWin;

  windowClosed = (typeof dataWin === 'undefined') ? true : dataWin.closed;

  if (windowClosed) {
    newWin = window.open('myurl' , "win" + name);
    el.data('winData',newWin);

    if (newWin) {
      newWin.focus()
    }
  }
  else {
    dataWin.focus();
  }
}
```

Make sure that the name you are passing to the function actually has a corresponding DOM element with an ID of 'id-NAME', or else your data will go nowhere.

**Please keep in mind:** for example in Google Chrome .focus() is blocked for any popup windows. So you won't be able to achieve the desired functionality there, using a simple call to .focus().